# How to arrange six columns in rows as per images?

Tags: jquery, json, webmethod

I treid to arrange images in six columns like but its repeating the images

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        alert('Hello');
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            url: "Default4.aspx/BindDatatable",
            data: "{}",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                var imgs;
                for (var i = 0; i < data.d.length; i++) {
                    $("#gvDetails").append("<tr><td><img src=" + data.d[i].ImagePath + " height='60px' width='100px' ></img></td><td><img src=" + data.d[i + 1].ImagePath + " height='60px' width='100px' ></img></td><td><img src=" + data.d[i + 2].ImagePath + " height='60px' width='100px' ></img></td><td><img src=" + data.d[i + 3].ImagePath + " height='60px' width='100px' ></img></td><td><img src=" + data.d[i + 4].ImagePath + " height='60px' width='100px' ></img></td><td><img src=" + data.d[i + 5].ImagePath + " height='60px' width='100px' ></img></td></tr>");
                }                                                                
            },
            error: function (result) {
                alert("Error");
            }
        });
    });
```

so how to avoid repeating images and arrange it as per images count?

Comment: `for (var i = 0; i < data.d.length; i++)` why like this ? change to `for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++)` and `data[i].ImagePath` --> to get path

Comment: what is data ?can you show the data json

Comment: `$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    url: "Default4.aspx/BindDatatable",
    data: "{}",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) {
        var imgs;
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            $("#gvDetails").append("<tr><td><img src=" + data[i].ImagePath + " height='60px' width='100px' /></td></tr>");
        }
    },
    error: function(result) {
        alert("Error");
    }
});` try this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TRY THIS Change Your success function something like that. note(i don't know what is your data return) it may work for you.

```
success: function (data) {
        var el = "<tr>";
        for (var i = 0; i < data.d.length; i++) {
        if ( i%6 == 0 ) {
            el += "</tr><tr>"
         }
        el += "<td><img src=" + data.d[i].ImagePath + " height='60px' width='100px' /></td>");
        } 
        el += '</tr>';
        $("#gvDetails").append( $(el) );                                                               
    }
```

Comment: your code working successfully..thanq very much..but if I want to add one label tag in another row then?

Comment: I want to display like this  el += "<td><img src=" + data.d[i].ImagePath + " height='60px' width='100px' /></br>";
                    el += "<Label class='label' >" + data.d[i].ImageAssignedName + "<Label></td>"; but for label text coming very long i cant break word by word